# Powershell error when environment variable is in path

Tags: powershell

When I try to get the file using the following path - it fails:

```
$path = Get-ItemProperty -Path "%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll"
```

or

```
$moduleVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll").FileVersion
```

is there a workaround for this in `powershell`?

When I specify the "full path" then it works fine, but I am not actually the one in control of what the value is. So I would expect the path to be resolved automatically as when you paste it directly in Explorer.. but it's not happening.

> Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\yyyy\%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll' because it does not exist.

**EDIT 1**: I have tried to apply the Regex fix but it does not work:

```
    $path = "%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll";
    $path = $path -replace "\%(.*?)\%", '$env:$1'
    $path2 = Get-ItemProperty -Path "%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll" #does not work
    $path3 = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$env:ProgramFiles\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll" #works
    $path4 = Get-ItemProperty -Path $path #does not work
```

Could somebody explain why `path3` works but `path4` isn't? the values are the same.. Still trying to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell itself doesn't support `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references such as `%ProgramFiles%` in [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`); the PowerShell equivalent is `$env:ProgramFiles`.<sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>If the variable name contains special chars., enclose the name in `{...}`; e.g., `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`.</sup>

Use the [`System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables) method to expand `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references such as `%ProgramFiles%` that are *embedded in a larger string*:

```
$path = [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
  '%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll'
)
```

<sup>Note: References to *undefined* env. variables are left untouched.</sup>

You can also embed the expression above directly in your cmdlet calls, using `(...)` (formatted for readability):

```
$path = Get-ItemProperty -Path (
  [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
    '%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll'
  )
)
```

---

<sup>[1] And if someone gave you a *verbatim* string containing such references, you'd have to *expand the string on demand*, which somewhat obscurely works as follows, for instance:

`$verbatim = '$env:ProgramFiles\IIS'; $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($verbatim)`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the `ProgramFiles` path by using `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles")`.
After it you can build the full path using [Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) function.

```
$programFiles = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles")
$aspPath = [IO.Path]::Combine($programFiles, "IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll")
```

Comment: This will work.. However, as was mentioned in a topic - I am not actually in charge of the link. What will I do if tomorrow this variable changes to %UserProfile% or there are going to be several of them?
I am currently trying to build some Regex replacement to `$env:XXXX` format.

Comment: Also note that in order to retrieve the value of an environment variable by name, something like `$env:ProgramFiles` is the simpler, PowerShell-idiomatic solution. Similarly, the PowerShell-idiomatic way of combining paths is to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet.